# How to find constraint 's column list in Sybase IQ?

Tags: constraints, sap-iq

I want to get columns list based on constraint name in Sybase IQ.
so who knows which system table could provide constraint columns information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select primary_tname,role,foreign_tname
            from sysforeignkeys
```

does this solve your problem? If you need indexes,it should be easy to join also the sysindex table, to also get the index information of the columns and then you got it all.